# How is the CyanogenMod "manual" focus mode controlled?

Tags: android-camera, cyanogenmod

**CyanogenMod apparently provides a "manual" focus mode without requiring the Camera2 API, but how can one control it?**

I discovered this mode on a OnePlus One, by calling:

```
camera.getParameters().getSupportedFocusModes()
```

The returned list includes an additional mode named `"manual"` that isn't documented in the standard Android [API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusMode()).  I can set this mode [e.g. using `setFocusMode("manual")`], but then what?

The [CyanogenMod Camera API source](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-12.0/core/java/android/hardware/Camera.java) shows that the mode is named `FOCUS_MODE_MANUAL_POSITION`, and it also provides the following:

```
 private static final int MANUAL_FOCUS_POS_TYPE_INDEX = 0;
 private static final int MANUAL_FOCUS_POS_TYPE_DAC = 1;
 /** @hide
 * Set focus position.
 *
 * @param pos user setting of focus position.
 */
 public void setFocusPosition(int type, int pos) {
   set(KEY_QC_MANUAL_FOCUS_POS_TYPE, Integer.toString(type));
   set(KEY_QC_MANUAL_FOCUS_POSITION, Integer.toString(pos));
 }

 /** @hide
 * Gets the current focus position.
 *
 * @return current focus position
 */
 public String getCurrentFocusPosition() {
    return get(KEY_QC_MANUAL_FOCUS_POSITION);
 }
```

But the `MANUAL_FOCUS_POS_TYPE_` constants are private and the methods are marked `@hide`.

So my question, again, is: **how would one control this "manual" focus mode?**